# Custom Tier Price not working in checkout page magento

Tags: magento

I have developed a custom module to meet my project requirements using Alan Storms tutorial for creating modules in magento.

I had the requirement of changing the price attribute dynamically on frontend based on a livefeed. Everysecond the feed is updated so every time the page refreshes a new price must be displayed for each product on the site.

I have override the product module and the price modules for this purpose. The issue is with tier pricing. When tier pricing comes into place I need to calculate the tier-price based on the live price.

For this also I managed to change using the price_type class override.

Now whenever an item is added to cart the tier-pricing was not working for that I wrote event_trigger ie an Observer which updates the tier_pricing on the event "checkout_cart_save_before" and here's my code

```
class My_Custom_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
   public function __construct()
   {
   }
   public function updateCartBasedOnLiveFeed($observer)
   {

          foreach ($observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */) 
          {
                        $tierPrices =   array();
                        $tierPrices =   $item->getProduct()->getTierPrice();
                        $itemPrice  =   $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
                        $i=0;
                        foreach($tierPrices as $key => $tierPrice)
                        {

                            if(!is_numeric($key))
                            {

                                    $updatedTierPrice                   =   $itemPrice - ($itemPrice * ($tierPrice['price']/100));
                                    $tierPrices[$key]['price']          =   $updatedTierPrice;
                                    $tierPrices[$key]['website_price']  =   $updatedTierPrice;  
                            }   
                            else 
                            {
                                if($tierPrice['price'] > 0)
                                {
                                    $updatedTierPrice                   =   $itemPrice - ($itemPrice * ($tierPrice['price']/100));
                                    $tierPrice['price']                 =   $updatedTierPrice;
                                    $tierPrice['website_price']         =   $updatedTierPrice;
                                    $tierPrices[$i]                     =   $tierPrice;
                                    $i++;   
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        $item->getProduct()->setData('tier_price',$tierPrices);

          }

   }
}
```

The above code works excellently in cart page. But when it comes to checkout page. It works for a single item and when tier-pricing comes into play it does apply cart prices.

Please help me with this.

I also tried using other events along with the above event.

Event: sales_quote_save_before

```
public function updateQuoteLive($observer)
   {
        $tierPrices =   array();

        $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote;

    $itemPrice  =   $quote_item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $tierPrices =   $quote_item->getProduct()->getTierPrice();

        $tierPricesSize =   sizeof($tierPrices);
        for($i=0;$i<$tierPricesSize;$i++)
        {
            $updatedTierPrice                   =   $itemPrice - ($itemPrice * ($tierPrices[$i]['price']/100));
            $tierPrices[$i]['price']            =   $updatedTierPrice;
            $tierPrices[$i]['website_price']    =   $updatedTierPrice;
        }

        $quote_item->getProduct()->setData('tier_price',$tierPrices);



   }
```

When I tried to print the getQuote() function available in Quote.php I find that the tier prices there are not the ones which I updated using the first event. So I think I need to update the price before saving the quote. Please any one help me and show the correct direction.

Please help me with this I am missing some important step. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better off "saving" the new price in to the database when you update.

Try something along the lines of:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$procuct->setPrice($updatedPrice);
```

This way when it comes to checkout it will be pulling in the correct price from the database (and avoids the headache of correcting it "mid-flight"

Comment: Thanks for your reply pzirkind..
But let me clear that the issue is not with price. But it is with "tier_price". If I add items with quantity 1 it is working fine.

Comment: But when we increase the quantity of the product to say some 10, 20 etc. Then we will have to calculate the tier price value based on again the live feed using and the values entered by admin. We need to multiple both values and update the tier pricing.

Answer (score 0):

i realized such a project like you. I have no sales_quote_save_before Observer. I only use the checkout_cart_save_before. Based on the session the price will be setted.

I realized that like this way:

```
public function updatePrice( $observer )
{   
try {
       $cart = $observer->getCart();
       $items = $cart->getItems();
       foreach($items as $item)
       {
       $item->setCustomPrice($price);
       $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
       }
     } catch ( Exception $e )
     {
       Mage::log( "checkout_cart_save_before: " . $e->getMessage() );
     }
}
```

I calcute the tierprices on the fly and with this Observer. All prices will be set up correct in the qoute.

Maybe you should try this way.

Regards boti

Answer (score 0):

At last figured out the issue and got the solution.

The problem was that in cart page or checkout page when the `getTierPrice() function` is called, which is present in `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Product.php`. It takes one parameter named $qty which is by default null. This function in turn calls the `function getTierPrice` which is present in `/app/code/core/Mage/Type/Price.php` file which  takes two parameters `$qty and $productObject.` By default $qty is null and when it is null the function returns an array of tier_prices. But when the $qty value is passed then the function returns a single for that particular quantity.

So, I wrote my own custom function which calculates the tier prices based no my requirements like

I overridden both the core files with my custom module following Alan Storm's tutorials.

I've extended Mage_Catalog_Model_Product with My_CustomModule_Model_Product  class and

then

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price with My_CustomModule_Model_Price

And then in /app/code/local/My/Custommodule/Model/Product.php

I added my custom code like

```
public function getTierPrice($qty=null)
    {
        if($qty)
        {
            return  $this->getPriceModel()->getCustomTierPrice($qty, $this); 
        }
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getTierPrice($qty, $this);
    }
```

Then in /app/code/local/My/Custommodule/Model/Price.php

```
<?php 

public function getCustomTierPrice($qty = null, $product)
    {
        $allGroups = Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL;
        $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');


        if (is_null($prices)) {
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
            if ($attribute) {
                $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
                $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');
            }
        }


 foreach($prices as $key => $customPrices)
        {
            if($prices[$key]['price'] < 1)
            {
                    $prices[$key]['price']          =   abs($product->getPrice() - ($productPrice * ($customPrices['price']/100)));
                    $prices[$key]['website_price']  =   $prices[$key]['price'];
            }

        }
}

which retured a customized value when $qty is passed and voila it worked.

I just posed this answer so that any one else who has similar requirement may get benefited with this.

?>
```